# Changing the visibility of a FloatingActionButton dependent on at least one check box in a RecyclerView being checked

Tags: android

I have a list of RecyclerView items with a CheckedTextView and FAB showing the plus sign to add more items to the list. Now I would like the FAB to change to a different symbol and a different action as soon as at least one of the check boxes is checked, see screenshot.
[image: Screenshot of the app]

To achieve this, I have created two FABs on the same position, one of them being hidden and one active.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/buttonLabel"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_meal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_local_dining_black_24dp" />
```

In my adapter, I wanted to achieve this as such:

```
        @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
        if (!itemStateArray.get(adapterPosition, false)) {
            foodItemView.setChecked(true);
            itemStateArray.put(adapterPosition, true);
        } else {
            foodItemView.setChecked(false);
            itemStateArray.put(adapterPosition, false);
        }

        // Check if at least one is checked
        if (isAtLeastOneChecked()) {
            FloatingActionButton fabMeal = parent.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.fab_meal);
            FloatingActionButton fabNew = parent.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.fab_add);
            fabNew.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fabMeal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, fabXXX.setVisibility(View.GONE) is not working, it gives me the following error message:

VisibilityAwareImageButton.setVisibility can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)

How can I set the visibility of the two FABs from within my Adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be a better approach to just have one FAB and change its icon / color? (yes it would; better performance - due to less views to render)

You could define an enum holding two States: `Meal` and `Add` (defaulting to `Add`). When an item is checked change it to `Meal`.

And if your state will change, change the color / icon of the FAB. The color can be changed like this: `fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(getResources().getColor(R.color.white)));` and the icon with `fab.setImageDrawable(...)`